# Can you still buy used panties in vending machines as a souvenir from Japan?

Tags: japan, souvenirs

In 1999 I came across a vending machine of used panties while hiking through Japan. Apparently it was made illegal in 1993, but still in 1999 they seem to be wide spread. Is this still the case, or are these vending machines no longer part of Japanese civilization.

Seems like an ultimate photo souvenir and I still regret not making a picture as proof for my strange experiences in Japan. People just don't believe this story.

Comment: Andra Grimm?? lol

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17362/241

Comment: I asked on lang-8.com . The people who replied (all Japanese) said that they'd never seen one.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm they did exist: http://www.oddee.com/item_96684.aspx

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if the machines still exist. But I have seen those being offered in Japanese Sex shops, for example in the [Akihabara District](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akihabara) in Tokyo. However, there is of course no telling if they are real. I can very well imagine that these are just normal panties, claimed to be used.

For the vending machine itself, there are two things involved here: A vending machine ([自動販売機](http://drmoku.com/jidohanbaiki-the-japanese-vending-machine/)) and a vendor of used girls clothing. Those include by the way also school uniforms etc ([ブルセラ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burusera)). Or simply "pants selling vending machine" (パンツの自動販売機orパンツの自販機) If you want to scour google search while using translate, you might find something. I went through a couple of search results and could not identify any clear hint of this still existing.

Comment: To be clear. I am not interested in buying used panties. The souvenir value is the vending machine, not its contents

Comment: @Andra Too late mate. I guess both our reputations are down the drain now :)

Comment: @Andra Yes, of course. That's what they say all.

Comment: @uncovery And it is too late to delete the question...

Comment: I'd rather see new panties claimed to be used, than the reverse...