# How can I wash my clothes in Lviv, Ukraine?

Tags: clothing, ukraine

I was going to wash my clothes in the current AirBnB room, but found that the washing machine was broken. I will stay at this room for relatively long so I'm looking for a way to wash my clothes.

If possible, I'm fine with using [something similar as a public washing machine in Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17362/how-should-i-wash-clothes-in-japan). Is there such service available in Lviv? Otherwise, is there any alternative to wash my clothes?

Comment: You can always use the sink...

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search ("lviv laundromat") found several dry-cleaners, and this:

> BUBBLES/Бульбашки 117 Volodymr Valeeki Str., Lviv
>
> Come visit Ukraine’s **only full-service Laundromat.** Brand new American equipment. Do your laundry yourself or let our happy workers take care of all your needs.

According to them, they're the only ones. I doubt that's true, but there's at least one place to go.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the public laundries in Lviv I just googled:

- korpus 5a, Heroiv UPA St, 73, L'viv
- Volodymyra Velykoho Street, 117, L'viv
- Kuznevycha St, 4, L'viv

You can google maps for word **пральня** yourself and try to find something close to the place, where you stay.